# How to escape the escape character in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

When I do an `ls` to my directory it shows a file with the name ''$'\033\033'. As I understood this was ASCII escape character pressed twice. I want to remove it with rm but I cannot escape the characters. Only through file manager I can delete it.

Comment: Is that leading double quote part of the name?

Comment: `rm $'\033\033'`?

Comment: @Shawn: those are two single quotes. `ls` actually displays it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should be able to use this command:

```
rm $'\033\033'
```

More info on how `$'...'` works can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

---

Note that `ls` might display a file named `$'\033\033'` as `''$'\033\033'`. Doesn't matter much though, `rm ''$'\033\033'` would also work fine as the two leading single quotes just form an empty string.

Comment: Thank you. It did not occur to me trying to remove the file without escaping any character. Sometimes the answer is right before your eyes.