# Where does the file ''$'\033\033\033' come from in Linux?

Tags: bash, shell

In my directory at a Linux server I have discovered a file with such a strange name.

From the command history I can track that it was probably created by this command:

```
 sudo docker logs <container_id> -n 200000 | less
```

I suspect I have entered some combination of letters in `less` (probably starting with **`s`** to save a file).

Do you know what exactly has happened?

P.S. If you want to remove such a file, see [How to escape the escape character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69589775/how-to-escape-the-escape-character-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that such a file is created when you type `s` in a piped `less` and then you are asked to enter the log file name. If you type triple `Escape` and then `Enter`, you will get such a file.

The command `s` is actually helpful to save the contents of a piped `less`.